# source MAC and destination Mac in netflow( or Sflow)

Tags: netflow, sflow

Is any way to see source MAC and destination MAC in netflow(or Sflow) data, like `nfdump -r <FILE_NAME>` for netflow data. Any best open source(or free) collector for Sflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MAC data is present in NetFlow packet you can view it easily with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). NetFlow v9 or above is required, and also device should be configured to send it.